# Fallo en peticion datos con json

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tengo una problema con una peticion de datos con json desde un formulario que me muestra este error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse ()
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (formulario.js:52)
¿A que se podria deber? Gracias

el modelo-admin.php

```
    <?php

$accion = $_POST['accion'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];



if($accion === 'login'){
    include '../funciones/conexion.php';
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT usuario, id, password FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $usuario);
        $stmt->execute();
        //Loguear el usuario
        $stmt->bind_result($nombre_usuario, $id_usuario, $pass_usuario);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $respuesta = array(
            'respuesta' => 'correcto',
            'nombre' => $nombre_usuario,
            'id' => $id_usuario,
            'pass'=> $pass_usuario,
            'columnas' => $stmt->affected_rows
        );
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        //En caso de un error, tomar la excepcion
        $respuesta = array(
        'pass' => $e->getMessage()
        );
    }
}
```

el js:

```
//  Leyendo los datos del formulario de crear usuario con JavaScript y Validando
eventListeners();

function eventListeners(){
    document.querySelector('#formulario').addEventListener('submit', validarRegistro);
}
function validarRegistro(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var usuario = document.querySelector('#usuario').value, //uso coma para declarar varias variables
        password = document.querySelector('#password').value,
        tipo = document.querySelector('#tipo').value;

    if(usuario === '' || password === ''){
        swal({
            type: "error",
            title: "Error",
            text: "Los 2 campos son obligatorios"
        });
    } else {            
        //datos  que se envian al servidor
        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append('usuario', usuario); 
        datos.append('password', password);
        datos.append('accion', tipo);

        console.log(datos.get('usuario'));

        //crear el llamado a ajax
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        //abrir la conexion
        xhr.open('POST', 'inc/modelos/modelo-admin.php', true);

        //retorno de datos
        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(this.status === 200){
                var respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                console.log(respuesta); //ESTA ES LA PARTE QUE ESTA MOSTRANDO  EL ERROR Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
                //Si la respuesta es correcta
                if(respuesta.respuesta === 'correcto'){
                    //si es un nuevo usuario
                    if(respuesta.tipo === 'crear'){
                        swal({
                            title: 'Usuario Creado',
                            text: 'El usuario se creó correctamente',
                            type: 'success'
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    //Hubo un error
                    swal({
                        title: 'Error',
                        text: 'Hubo un error',
                        type: 'error'
                    })
                }

            }
        }

        //Enviar la peticion
        xhr.send(datos);
    }

}
```

Comment: Puede hacer un echo en el script de php y adjuntar el json generado?

Comment: No entiendo ¿un echo $respuesta; despues de despues de $respuesta = array('respuesta' => 'correcto','nombre' => $nombre_usuario,'id' => $id_usuario,'pass' => $pass_usuario,'columnas' => $stmt->affected_rows); ???
Lo acabo de hacer esto pero no muestra nada.

Comment: Estoy leyendo detenidamente el código y no acabo de entender lo que quiere conseguir, asumiendo que el php funcione como debería en el javascript primero abre una conexion POST al script php, luego toma los datos que recibe para luego volverlos a mandar? Cómo sabes que la primera llamada va a funcionar si no le está pasando ningún parametro tales como el user o la pass? Cual es exactamente el funcionamiento que pretende que tenga el codigo?

Comment: el user y pass se  mandan por post al principio del php a traves de formulario que no puse para no hacer tan larga la pregunta:
Se pasan con:
$password = $_POST['password'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
¿Sabes que podria estar mal escrito? No se si es el array creado en el php o la forma de leerlo. ¿alguna idea?
Gracias en cualquier caso
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
esto funciona bien porque ya lo testee. Lo que va mal es el parse del json que me da el error que mencione antes:
var respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
console.log(respuesta);

Comment: El único error que se me ocurre teniendo en cuenta que tecnicamente el js no debería estar mal si lo he interpretado bien, es que no haces nada con la variable `$respuesta`, por lo que podría ser por eso por lo que no funciona, podrías hacer un `echo $respuesta` en el script php y comprobar si funciona.

Comment: Bueno estoy probando hacer echo $respuesta y me sale este error: VM134:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>). Pero si pongo: echo json_encode($respuesta); si me muestra lo que tengo en el array. Mi pregunta es ¿por que esta mostrando ese error en el primer caso?

Comment: Porque tendrás un error de sintaxis al encodear el JSON

Comment: ¿un error? lo que se pasa al json_encode es un array asociativo bastante normal. El error dice que hay  un inesperado token < en posicion 0  que seria el valor: 'respuesta' => 'correcto', ¿que error ves tu aqui?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te falta devolver la respuesta desde el backend en formato `json`

```
try {
 ...
 $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'correcto',
        'nombre' => $nombre_usuario,
        'id' => $id_usuario,
        'pass'=> $pass_usuario,
        'columnas' => $stmt->affected_rows
    );

    echo json_encode($respuesta);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    //En caso de un error, tomar la excepcion
    $respuesta = array(
    'pass' => $e->getMessage()
    );

    echo json_encode($respuesta);
}
```

Y asegurarte de que la respuesta sea UTF8, de lo contrario el json_encode escribirá un null.

PD: un simple `echo $respuesta` gatillará el error `array to string conversion`. Por eso debes usar `json_encode`.

Comment: Entonces en php se genera un array asociativo que posteriormente con json_encode se convierte en un string json que, a su vez es parseado en var respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); para convertirlo en un objeto javascript ¿Es asi esto? Estoy intentando razonarlo para intentar entender el funcionamiento. Si hay algo que matizar, por favor, dime.
Mil gracias

Comment: Es justamente como lo describiste.